# You own $19.75 in dimes and quarters - there are 100 coins in all - how many dimes?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I have been stuck on this problem for 30+ minutes and I can't seem to get the correct answer; there must be something that I am missing/doing wrong!!

- You own $19.75 in *dimes* and *quarters*
- There are 100 coins in all
- How many dimes are there?

My variables:

$d$ = dimes,
$q$ = quarters

My equations:

$$19.75 = 10d + 25q$$

$$100 = d + q$$

I have done problems like this before, system of equations, but I cannot, for some unknown reason (to me), find the correct answer.

It always comes out with like 3 decimal places, and numbers that *are not* divisible.

Any help, even hints, would be *truly* appreciated! 
Thanks!

What I have tried:

$-10(100) = (d + q)-10 [=] -1000 = -10d - 10q$

$19.75 = 10d + 25q$

$+$

$-1000 = -10d - 10q$

Comment: In your first equation, 19.75 is in units of dollars, but 10 and 25 are cents. You need to use 1975 instead of 19.75.

Comment: But, why is 19.75 suddenly _1975_? That is changing the equation, no (how does this work in math)?

Comment: 19.75 dollars is the same as 1975 cents. Since the right hand side $10d + 25q$ is in cents, the left hand side also needs to be in cents. Think about this, one dollar equals 100 cents. Does that mean that $1 = 100$? No, because the units of the left and right hand sides do not agree.

Comment: In other words, yes, changing 19.75 to 1975 will change the equation. But that is good in this case, because it changes an incorrect question to a correct one. Another alternative would be to express everything in dollars, in which case the equation would be $19.75 = 0.10d + 0.25q$.

Comment: Hmm.. that seems logical... okay - I will try that out and tell you what I get

Comment: You can either to the whole thing in dollars, where a dime is worth $\$0.10.$  Or do the whole thing in cents where $\$19.75 = 1975$ cents.  But you cannot use both units at the same time.. at least not until you understand more about changing units.

Comment: @DougM - I see.. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all 100 of your coins were quarters, you'd have \$25.00.  That's too much; you're only supposed to have \$19.75, which is \$5.25 less. So you need to replace some of those 100 quarters with dimes.  Every time you replace a quarter with a dime, the amount of money decreases by \$0.15.  How many of these \$0.15 decreases are needed in order to get a total decrease of \$5.25? Well, 5.25 divided by 0.15 is 35, so you'll need 35 quarter-to-dime replacements. The result will be 65 quarters and 35 dimes.  (Since I don't trust my ability to do arithmetic, I should check the answer: $(65\times0.25)+ (35\times0.10)=16.25+3.50=19.75$.)